# How can I subtract a circle from an image in Sketch?

Tags: sketch-app

I have a bitmap and I want to subtract a circle show the background gradient shows through. How can I do that?

Answer (score 10):

**We can subtract a circle from image in sketch-app using a rectangle shape with hole (subtracted circle shape) as mask for the image (bitmap/ png/jpeg).**

Example:

Step 1:
Image above background gradient.

[image]

Step 2:
Create a rectangle shape (black color used in example) with same size as image. Place it above image.

[image]

Step 3:
Create a circle (white color used in example) above rectangle for the hole.

[image]

Step 4:
Subtract circle from rectangle.

4.1 Select both circle and rectangle shape.

4.2 Select "Layer" > "Combine" > "Subtract"

[image]

Step 5:
Select the "rectangle with hole" shape as mask for the image.

5.1 Select the Combined shape and image

5.2 Select "Layer" > "Mask" > "Use as mask"

[image]